# Hosting content as static page using Flask

Tags: python, google-maps, flask, static, plotly

I have a flask application that draws some HTML graphs and a Google Map.

Every time I refresh my browser it runs my `index()` method, which is my only method in my `views.py`. This method gathers the data from a set of files, and calculates the graphs, the Google Map and so forth.

This is very loading heavy and I was wondering if there's some kind of way that I can run this method whenever I do `python run.py` instead of calculating everything when I load my index page? I want to just save the content of my index method and show it instantly when the page is loaded, so all of the content isn't loaded when the page is refreshed.

Is this doable in any way?

## Views.py

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    
    """Read from .json files. Generate a buttload of graphs, and data to return to index.html"""

    return render_template('index.html',
                       trips=trips,
                       ids=ids,
                       graphJSON=graphJSON,
                       markerList=markerList,
                       routeCoordinates=routeCoordinates,
                       center=center)
```

The above makes all of the data grathering, drawing and so forth run whenever someone refreshes the page which is not my Intention. I just want to run the functions whenever the "main file" (run.py) is run and then visualize the data on my index page.

Comment: Sounds like you don't need Flask. Write a script that generates an HTML file (you can still use Jinja2 for that) and serve it which Nginx.

Comment: Could be done like that I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the heavy loading in your `__init__.py` file and store the values in a variable their. Then just import it in your `views.py`.

For example:

#### `__init__.py`

```
def some_heavy_loading():
    ...
    return values

VALUES = some_heavy_loading()
```

#### `views.py`

```
import VALUES
...
    def index():
    ...
    return render_template('index.html',
                   values=VALUES)
```

Comment: How would I store it in a variable and how would I load that in my views.py?

Comment: Exactly like I did in the example?

Comment: My bad. Sorry. I didn't see the example when viewing on my phone :P

Comment: When I try this is just get `ImportError: No module named 'VALUES'`